# Not able to ping router ip from other nodes in network

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

I am having openstack installed with packstack and my dashboard is running.

**Infrastructure Details :**

VM1(CentOS7) : `10.151.1.116` Compute Node

VM2(CentOS7) : `10.151.1.230` Controller Node

**Network details :**

**Public Network :** `10.151.1.240 to 10.151.1.245`

**Private Network :** `172.16.10.0/24` DHCP ENABLED

**Commands to create Networks and Router:**

```
neutron net-create extnet --provider:network_type flat --provider:physical_network extnet --router:external=True --shared


openstack subnet create --network extnet --allocation-pool start=10.151.1.240,end=10.151.1.245 --gateway 10.151.1.1 --subnet-range 10.151.1.0/24 extnet

openstack network create private

openstack subnet create --network private --gateway 172.16.10.1 --subnet-range 172.16.10.0/24 private

openstack router create router

neutron router-interface-add router private
neutron router-gateway-set router extnet
```

After above steps I have restarted the network.
Now My router external interface get ip `10.151.1.242`

I am able to ping this ip from controller node(`i.e 10.151.1.230`) but not from any other nodes in network like my localmachine which is having ip (`10.122.19.138`).

**Note :**  I have allowed all protocols including ICMP from security groups.

Version of openstack : **openstack-queens**

**Answerfile :** https://gist.github.com/cthakar/277f7c813adf68b977b197d8c5a0195f

Can anyone help me for this what configuration I missed it ? It would be a great help.

Thank you!